# HtmlUnit, textbox updated by ajax

Tags: ajax, htmlunit

I am trying to create a character on webpage using their random name generator, it has text link for ajax that puts new random link in text field above when you click it

```
<a href="./ajax_suggestname.php" ajaxcip="true" ajaxcip_target="#charactername" ajaxcip_datatype="Attributes">suggest name</a>
```

I get anchor like this

```
private HtmlAnchor getAnchorByAttribute(HtmlPage managementPage, String attribute) {
    for (HtmlAnchor anchor : managementPage.getAnchors()) {
        if (anchor.asText().equals(attribute)) {
            return anchor;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then I try to get the updated name from field like this

```
private String getSuggestName(HtmlPage managementPage, HtmlForm form) throws IOException {
    HtmlAnchor suggestName = getAnchorByAttribute(managementPage, "suggest name");
    suggestName.click();
    int tries = 10;
    while (tries-- > 0 && form.getInputByName("name").getValueAttribute().isEmpty()) {
        synchronized (managementPage) {
            try {
                managementPage.wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return form.getInputByName("name").getValueAttribute();
}
```

generating name takes less than second, however function always returns an empty string.
The click method I am calling on anchor returns new page that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>
```

While I would expect it to be the same form as before but with generated name.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem few days ago, I came to know that you have to wait for execution for ajax requests, best is to retrying for some time until page is not updated (using any condition) here is example of code (which works for me)

```
int input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size();
int tries = 5; 
while (tries > 0 && input_length < 12) { //you can change number of tries and condition according to your need
    tries--;
    synchronized (page) {
        page.wait(2000); //wait
    }
    input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size(); //input length is example of condtion
}
```